# Did VB 6/.NET interop recently get broken by a Windows update?

Tags: .net, windows, vb6, windows-update

Recently a VB 6 application using .NET 1.1/2.0 components stopped working on my companies XP machines. The IT department was installing Windows patches at the time, so I'm wondering if anyone has heard of an update breaking VB 6/.NET interop?

Comment: Not that I know of. If you post some more details about the problem, maybe we could help track down the  cause?

Comment: There was a security patch for .Net 2.0 that affected how errors are being raised in both .net 1.1 and 2.0.  There did not break my COM interop but I did more errors across COM.

Comment: That might have been it, as the old components were definitely written in .NET 1.1.

Comment: I don't know about this in particular, but Windows updates frequently break COM component registrations, causing software to need to be reinstalled.  Usually, re-installing the broken program or identifying and manually re-registering the component using regsvr32 fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running the COM+ components as proxies against other servers? If so, I've had problems before when installing e.g. SP2 for Windows 2003 server, in that the COM+ settings (Component Services, root node) have had the "remote activation" security setting permission missing after the update. Don't know if this is your problem, though.